# Flexbox rows to use top menu and flexible bottom content

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I get all elements to fit in a container element that is fixed to the size of the window?

I have a container element that is fixed position and flexbox, it does not stay within window. The menu is 50px and I want the main element to fill the remainder of the window height.

I have a container `my-app` and inside it, 2 vertically stacked elements (flex-direction = column). It works as expected in Chrome but not Edge or Firefox.

```
my-app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

app-menu {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightcoral;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

app-my-view {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/2-column-scroll-v2

I've got it working by using a fixed position menu sticking to the top and using padding to offset menu height in the main content area. However I thought it would be better to use approach with 2 stacked elements without using fixed menu .

See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/2-column-scroll-v1

Comment: if I may, but it's already working as you have `flex: 1` on `app-my-view`?

Comment: Which browser are you using? it doesn't work with Edge but it does work in Chrome, also I had the wrong project linked for the working version. Updated it.